# see what pull requests depend on my branch (github)

Tags: github

I recently merged a branch into master and want to delete it now that I'm done with it. But github tells me that I can't delete it because some open pull request depends on it. How do I find out which pull requests depend on this branch?

Comment: Can you link the repository please?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. It's github enterprise...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find the open pull requests which depend on a particular branch called `foo` (i.e. pull requests for merging other branches into branch `foo`), use the following Filter query in the Pull requests tab:

`is:pr base:foo is:open`

This will identify the Pull Requests preventing the deletion of branch `foo`

[image: GitHub Pull requests tab]

Answer (score 0):

I found that one of my open pull requests was trying to merge into the branch I was trying to delete, instead of merging into master as it was supposed to. Fixing this allowed me to delete my branch.

I could not find a way to easily view all the open pull requests involving any given branch, so I had to go through my open PRs one by one.